# How do i get the selected option from an Jquery UI selectmenu object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Jquery UI selectmenu object which I have generated dynamically from a database.

I need to get the selected text from it, if it wasn't an Jqueryu UI object I could use this at **onChange** event like that:

```
$('#l1').change(function() {
    var selectedText= $('#l1 option:selected').text();
....
```

How could I get the same value for Jquery UI object?
I mention that I can't rely on .val() property because all are 0.
I did try this

```
var selectedText = $(this).find(':selected').text();
```

without success.

Comment: Why the downvote? Would be useful to know otherwise  ....  I could imagine anything.

Answer (score 1):

Find out!

It's about how I relate to the on change event.

When I use Jquery UI I have to use:

**$('#l1').selectmenu({change: function (event, data)  {**

instead of:

$('#l1').change(function() {

**Now I will try to find why is it that way?**

Comment: That because selectmenu creates new DOM elements to "replace" the original `<select>`, which is hidden. So it is no longer `<select>` and `<option>` that user see... But a bunch of `<ul>`, `<li>` and `<div>` elements. --- And as you found out by yourself (+1 for that), the events are handled from within the selectmenu instance.